# Custom Elements do not fire inline custom events

Tags: javascript, inline, custom-element, custom-events

I tried to catch inline custom events from custom elements with the following code. I got only 'external success', never 'inline success' on logs.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Note : I have tried also to replace HTMLELement by HTMLDivElement/is: same result

```js
customElements.define(
'test-it',class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.children[0].addEventListener('click', e=>this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('testevent', {detail:'test'})))
  };
}
);

document.getElementsByTagName('test-it')[0].addEventListener('testevent', ()=>{console.log('external success')});
```

```html
<test-it id="test" ontestevent="console.log('inline success');">
  <div>Minimal test</div>
</test-it>
```

Comment: I guess it's not about the custom element, [it's about the custom event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42321978/11151040).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`testevent` is not a valid HTML5 Global Event Handler:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers

That means `ontestevent="..."` is just an **attribute** and **not** a `onEvent` handler.

You can **not** create such a handler yourself.

That is why `addEventListener` was created

PS. For your future Web Components adventures: Sending Events from **inside** shadowDOM (you are not using now) require `composed:true` for CustomEvents to *escape* shadowDOM

Comment: you can btw, technically, no problem to make it work

Comment: I'd love to see how; in Web Components I prefer **inline** handlers... and I mean true **inline** handlers like OP his notation **without** ``eval`` trickery.

Comment: You already doing eval by placing things to attrs

Comment: Then **how** can I create my own Global Event Handler? ``<div onhandler="console.log(42)">``

Comment: I thought that every attribute starting with on will match. But there is a limited list working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

thanks [BOZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11151040/boz), works with the following addition but custom event *detail* is lost (code updated).

```js
if ( this.ontestevent ) this.ontestevent(); else eval(this.getAttribute('ontestevent'));
```

```js
customElements.define(
'test-it',class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.children[0].addEventListener(
      'click', 
      e=>{
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('testevent', {detail:'test'}));
        if ( this.ontestevent ) this.ontestevent(); else eval(this.getAttribute('ontestevent'));
    })
  };
}
);

document.getElementsByTagName('test-it')[0].addEventListener('testevent', (e)=>{console.log('external success:'+e.detail)});
```

```html
<test-it ontestevent="console.log('inline success:'+e.detail);">
  <div>Minimal test</div>
</test-it>
```